# Cassandra in Docker cant connect from outside

Tags: docker, cassandra

Hi I am new to word Docker and Cassandar. I have a problem connecting to Cassandra in Docker from my computer.

I run container Cassandra and I see that exposed ips and ports are 192.168.99.100:9042.(first image) In docker I can even see that "Test cluster" is running but when I want to connect to Cassandra by NoSQL Manager for Cassandra there is always error message "None of the hosts tried for query are available".

Thank you.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't expose a port. 9042 is docker port. 
When you run the docker image you must remember this:

```
docker run -p 9042:9042 image-name
```

first 9042 define the port number where outer world will connect and 2nd 9042 defines docker's port number which will be bound with outer port number 9042.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response:)